# About APScheduler.reschedule_job() how to update new params

Tags: python, apscheduler

As my title, I dont know how to update params when I reschedule my old job, show my code below:

```
import os
from apscheduler.schedulers.background import BackgroundScheduler


def test(s):
    print(s)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    scheduler = BackgroundScheduler()
    scheduler.add_job(test, 'interval', seconds=3, args=['old params'], id="y")
    print('Press Ctrl+{0} to exit'.format('Break' if os.name == 'nt' else 'C'))
    try:
        scheduler.start()
    except (KeyboardInterrupt, SystemExit):
        pass

    # while True:
    scheduler.reschedule_job("y", trigger="interval", seconds=10)


    while True:
        pass
```

In the period of `add_job`, I could use **args** send params inside, but when I wanna update my job, I use `reschedule_job`, yes, I saw offical docs that it works, but I dont know how to update my old params **old params** to new params **new params** in the period of `reschedule_job`

Getting help!!! Waitting for you online thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]
from the source code. it seems that `reschedule_job` can not modify other parameters.
you can use `modify` instead of `reschedule_job`

example:

```
scheduler = BackgroundScheduler()
scheduler.add_job(test, 'interval', seconds=3, args=['old params'], id="y")

job = scheduler.get_job(job_id="y")
job.modify(
    trigger='interval',
    seconds=10
)
```

Comment: Thanks, You anwser just what Im doing, Im using `modify` to replace old params at first and `reschedule_job` reschedule job in the second, thanks again!!